# Change schema of query dynamically based on the connection DEV/SIT/PROD

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a native query in Spring Data JPA:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer>{       
    @Query(value = "select * from DEV.Book where find_in_set(market)", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Book> findBooksByMarcket(@Param("market") String market);
}
```

Now I want to change the `DEV.Book` based on my connection `SIT/PROD` dynamically, based on the connection I tried to pass a string into native query which didn't work. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should set Schema in your connection and leave the query without schema.

Answer (score 0):

You should find some way to remove the namespace from the query.

You could for example have three databases without any namespace. If you configure the database connection via properties you can easily switch by supplying different startup properties or property files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in this way:

```
@Override
public List<Book> findBooksByMarcket(String market) {

    TypedQuery query = em.createNativeQuery("select * from DEV.Book where find_in_set(?)", Book.class);
    query.setParameter(1, market);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```